Why does my script run infinitely and stops other payloads in Winforms?
Everything works fine except this script and its a really small problem. When it runs it opens a yes or no window and clicking yes makes the cd audio door open and close after 7 seconds but it instead does it infinitely and no other processes work while it does. Here's the code:
namespace Floydziak4
{
    public class Payload
    {
        [DllImport("winmm.dll", EntryPoint = "mciSendString")]
        public static extern int mciSendString(string lpstrCommand, string lpstrReturnString, int uRetrunLenght, int hwndCallback);

public void takczynie()
{
    DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show("text1", "text2", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    if (dialog == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        try
        {
            int result = mciSendString("set cdaudio door open", null, 0, 0);
            Thread.Sleep(7000)
            result = mciSendString("set cdaudio door close", null, 0, 0);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            int result = mciSendString("set cdaudio door open", null, 0, 0);
            Thread.Sleep(7000)
            result = mciSendString("set cdaudio door close", null, 0, 0);
        }

    }
    else
    {
        {
            other process here
        }
    }
}

The break; command in the script that manages all the payloads and scripts doesn't make it run once and I dont know why because it works everywhere but there, but this specific script is much longer and more advanced than the others so I expected problems with it. I tried putting break; everywhere in the code but it doesnt work.

"I tried putting break; everywhere in the code" break is only valid inside loops (do, while, for) and switches. I don't see any of those in the code you've posted. Why do you have duplicate code for the try and catch block? "but it instead does it infinitely" How do you call the takczynie method? Are you sure that the mciSendString calls work correctly?

What does this mean: [...] but it instead does it infinitely? -- Thread.Sleep() suspends the current Thread, the UI Thread probably, so you can do nothing in the meanwhile -- With a Thread.Sleep() after mciSendString(), you're also risking a Blue Screen of Death. Not sure you actually have it there, since there's no semicolon at the end. Looks like a last-minute substitute for something else

Infinitely, or twice? Does it pop up the dialog more than once?

@gunr2171 "break is only valid inside loops (do, while, for) and switches. I don't see any of those in the code you've posted" thats what visual studio is telling me but i dont know how to make it a loop. "Why do you have duplicate code for the try and catch block?" i didnt know what else to put there and now that im thinking about it could be the cause of it. "Are you sure that the mciSendString calls work correctly?" i think so

@Jimi "What does this mean: [...] but it instead does it infinitely?" my cdaudio door opens and closes until i close the program and other functions of the program stop working.

@iakobski The dialog box with yes or no pops up and when you click yes everything else stops showing up and the cdaudio door starts to open and close until you close the program

I'm struggling to see how the code you show can get into a loop. I suggest you start by putting something else in the catch, like logging the exception. Then run the program in a debugger, stepping through that function to see where it fails or where it loops.
